# Split period into day parts java

Tags: java, timestamp

I have the following datetimes:

```
Start: 2013-1-1  00:00:00.000
End:   2013-1-31 23:59:59.599
```

How can I split that in parts int periods for give days every period.

For Example if days=1:

```
2013-1-1  00:00:00.000-> 01-01-2013 23:59:59
2013-1-2  00:00:00.000 -> 2013-1-2  23:59:59
2013-1-3  00:00:00.000 -> 2013-1-3  23:59:59 
etc...
```

I have read this post [Split period into month parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086103/split-period-into-month-parts) for c# and I try to do it like:

```
private static ArrayList<Period>  splitPeriods(int days){
        ArrayList<Period> list = new ArrayList<>();
        java.sql.Timestamp start = new Timestamp(110, 0, 1, 00, 00, 00, 00);
        java.sql.Timestamp end = new Timestamp(  110, 2, 1, 00, 00, 00, 00);
        Timestamp current = start;
        Period period;
        while(current.before(end)){
            period = new Period();
            period.setStart(current);
            current.setDate((current.getDate()+days));    
            period.setEnd(current);

            System.out.println(period.getStart() +"\t"+period.getEnd());

        }
        return list;
    }
```

Class Period:

```
public class Period {

    private java.sql.Timestamp end;
    private java.sql.Timestamp start;

//..set - get
}
```

but the output of period is:

```
2013-1-2  00:00:00.000 -> 2013-1-2  00:00:00.000
2013-1-3  00:00:00.000 -> 2013-1-3  00:00:00.000
etc...
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked `java.text.DateFormat` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. In fact, have you even googled how to convert a String into a Date in java?

Comment: I have checked it, but I can't understand where can I use it...

Comment: SJuan76 you can see the solution in my answer.
java.text.DateFormat and java.text.SimpleDateFormat don't solve the solution. So you can google it....!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. Ι create new timestamps for start period and end period. 
Start period takes the value Of  current timestamp before increment.
end period takes the value Of  current timestamp after increment.

code:

Period class

```
public class Period {

    private java.sql.Timestamp end;
    private java.sql.Timestamp start;

//..set - get
}
```

Main class

```
public class MainClass{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Period> list = splitPeriods(15); 

    }

private static ArrayList<Period>  splitPeriods(int days){
        ArrayList<Period> list = new ArrayList<>();
        java.sql.Timestamp start = new Timestamp(110, 2, 1, 00, 00, 00, 00); //start 1 March 2010
        java.sql.Timestamp end = new Timestamp(  110, 3, 30, 00, 00, 00, 00); //end 30 April 2010
        Timestamp current = start;
        Period period;
        while(current.before(end)){
            period = new Period();
            //new timestamp for start Period
            java.sql.Timestamp startPeriod = new Timestamp(current.getTime());
            //change current timestamp
            current.setDate((current.getDate()+days));    

            //new timestamp for end period.
            //set prev day and time 23:59:59...
            java.sql.Timestamp endPeriod = new Timestamp(current.getTime());
            endPeriod.setDate(endPeriod.getDate()-1);
            endPeriod.setHours(23);
            endPeriod.setMinutes(59);
            endPeriod.setSeconds(59);
            endPeriod.setNanos(599999999);

            //add to list
            period.setStart(startPeriod);
            period.setEnd(endPeriod);

            System.out.println(period.getStart() +"\t"+period.getEnd());

        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
input
start: 1 March 2010
end: 30 April 2010
```

```
output
2010-03-01 00:00:00.0   2010-03-15 23:59:59.599999999
2010-03-16 00:00:00.0   2010-03-30 23:59:59.599999999
2010-03-31 00:00:00.0   2010-04-14 23:59:59.599999999
2010-04-15 00:00:00.0   2010-04-29 23:59:59.599999999
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a tricky regex problem! And I think this difficulty should be seen as evidence that regex may not be the best tool for the job.

With the [multiline flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) activated, this regular expression works:

- Find what: `Start: ([0-9]{4}(?:-[0-9]{1,2}){2} +(?:[0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2})(?:\.[0-9]{2,3})?\nEnd:   ([0-9]{4}(?:-[0-9]{1,2}){2} +(?:[0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2})(?:\.[0-9]{2,3})?\n`
- Replace with: `$1 -> $2`
- Try it: http://regex101.com/r/lQ0wR9/1

Free spaced:

- `Start: ([0-9]{4}`: `Start`, (start capture group), 4 digits
- (?:-[0-9]{1,2}){2} +`: a dash followed by two digits (*twice*)
- `(?:[0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2})`: two digits then a colon (*twice*), followed by two digits
- `(?:\.[0-9]{2,3})?`: Optional: dot followed by two-or-three digits
- `\r\n`: Newline
- `End:   ...`: `End` followed by the same regex as after `Start`

Input:

```
Start: 2013-1-1  00:00:00.000
End:   2013-1-31 23:59:59.59
Start: 2013-1-1  00:00:00.000
End:   2013-1-1  23:59:59
Start: 2013-1-2  00:00:00.000
End:   2013-1-2  23:59:59
Start: 2013-1-3  00:00:00.000
End:   2013-1-3  23:59:59
```

Java:

```
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class StartEndDateLinesToArrowSingleLine  {
   private static final String LINE_SEP = System.getProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {

      String regexMain = "([0-9]{4}(?:-[0-9]{1,2}){2} +" +
         "(?:[0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2})" +
         "(?:\\.[0-9]{2,3})?" + LINE_SEP;
      String findWhatRegex = "Start: " + regexMain + "End:   " + regexMain;
      String rplcWith = "$1 -> $2";

      String input = new StringBuilder().
         append("Start: 2013-1-1  00:00:00.000").append(LINE_SEP).
         append("End:   2013-1-31 23:59:59.599").append(LINE_SEP).
         append("Start: 2013-1-1  00:00:00.000").append(LINE_SEP).
         append("End:   2013-1-1  23:59:59"    ).append(LINE_SEP).
         append("Start: 2013-1-2  00:00:00.000").append(LINE_SEP).
         append("End:   2013-1-2  23:59:59"    ).append(LINE_SEP).
         append("Start: 2013-1-3  00:00:00.000").append(LINE_SEP).
         append("End:   2013-1-3  23:59:59"    ).append(LINE_SEP).toString();

      Matcher mtchr = Pattern.compile(findWhatRegex, Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input);

      StringBuffer bfr = new StringBuffer();
      while(mtchr.find())  {
         bfr.setLength(0);
         mtchr.appendReplacement(bfr, rplcWith);
         bfr.append(LINE_SEP);
         mtchr.appendTail(bfr);
         mtchr.reset(bfr.toString());
      }
      System.out.println(bfr.toString());
   }
}
```

Output:

```
2013-1-1  00:00:00 -> 2013-1-31 23:59:59
2013-1-1  00:00:00 -> 2013-1-1  23:59:59
2013-1-2  00:00:00 -> 2013-1-2  23:59:59
2013-1-3  00:00:00 -> 2013-1-3  23:59:59
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<DaySlot> getDaySlots(Date start, Date end) {
    List<DaySlot> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    Date current = start;
    while(current.before(end)) {
        Date startOfTheDay = getStartOfTheDay(current);
        Date endOfTheDay = getEndOfTheDay(startOfTheDay);
        ret.add(new DaySlot(current, endOfTheDay.before(end)? endOfTheDay: end));
        current = getNextDay(startOfTheDay);
    }
    return ret;
}



private LocalDate getDateOnly(Date date) {
    return date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
}

private Date getStartOfTheDay(Date current) {
    return Date.from(getDateOnly(current).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}

private Date getNextDay(Date startOftheDay) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(startOftheDay);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    return calendar.getTime();
}

private Date getEndOfTheDay(Date startOftheDay) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(startOftheDay);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 599);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

The call looks like below:

```
    List<DaySlot> daySlots = getDaySlots(durationStartTime, durationEndTime);
```